# Подскажите регулярки для строки содержащей больше 1-2 слов?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста регулярки:

- "строка содержит более одного слова"
- "строка содержит более двух слов"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да тупо в лоб.

> строка содержит более одного слова

```
/\w+\s+\w+/
```

> строка содержит более двух слов

```
/\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+/
```

При условии, что разделителем между словами считаем именно `\s` (то есть знаки препинания не учитываем).

Comment: для определения границы слова можно использовать `\b` [wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.83.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B8_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.B8)

Comment: Используйте, я не против :-)

Comment: @MaxTimakov здесь не нужны границы слов... Задачу можно вовсе решить так: `\w\W+\w` - 1 вариант, `\w\W+\w\W+\w` второй вариант. И по этой же причине не ставлю плюс ответу :) Слова могут быть разделены не только пробелами.

Answer (score 2):

> строка содержит более **N** слов

Рассмотрим общий случай.
Слова могут разделять любые символы, которые не относятся к буквам, то есть символьный класс `\W`
Слово, соответственно, будет `\w+`

```
(?:\w+\W+){N}\w
```

Это общий вид выражения. В случае, `N = 1` можно упростить до такого:

```
\w\W+\w
```

В случае `N = 2` будет выглядеть так:

```
(?:\w+\W+){2}\w
```

Comment: Вы были правы, мое выражение не учитывает такой случай, чего я сразу не заметил. Переделать его сейчас не могу. :) Плюс вам